# I built a locomotive and I want to connect a TSU-2200 sound card to it which operates on 3.7 v to 22 v. my system operates on 24 volts

Tags: sound, card, train

I have built a locomotive, which operates from a 24-volt alternator through a 300 amp controller then to 6, 350-watt 24-volt motors. I have a TSU-2200 digital sound decoder that operates on a voltage between 3.7-volts-22-volts, the problem is that where they are connected the voltages is 24-volt or more, is it possible to connect a resistor in the circuit so that I can get 20 volts to my sound card instead of the 24-volt George

Comment: A resistor in series with a load reduces the maximum current, it does not regulate and reduce the voltage. When the current is low then the load receives the maximum input voltage. When the load current is high then it gets a low voltage. You do not want that.

Comment: Thank you so much. George

Answer (score 4):

You should use a DC-DC converter or voltage regulator rather than a resistor. The voltage dropped by a resistor will vary depending on the current drawn by your sound card.  The voltage regulator will keep the voltage constant regardless of the current drawn by the sound card (within limits, of course).

The sound card will draw varying current, depending on the volume of sound produced.

Comment: A voltage regulator, rather than a crude voltage dropper, will give a more stable supply with some protection for the sound card from voltage spikes.  Electric motors can produce quite a lot of electrical noise.

Comment: Thanks for your information

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a separate battery just for the sound card? A rechargeable unit can be swapped or recharged when needed. Having 2 batteries on the locomotive allows you to switch over to the good battery if the main one goes flat unexpectedly.

Comment: Thanks so much for that information. I already have two batteries, it's really where I connect the sound card to the motor terminals, so that as you raise your speed so your sound changes, George.